# Clarification of one-to-many navigation properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm a bit confused by conflicting examples of one-to-many model relationships using EF that I'm seeing online.

One video I watched setup a relationship between tables like so:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }   
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }

    public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
}
```

So a `Customer` can only have one `CustomerType`, but a `CustomerType` can be used by many `Customers`. This code works fine, I can fetch a `Customer`'s `CustomerType` with LINQ using `Include`.

Now I'm looking at another resource showing the same kind of relationship:

```
public partial class Standard
{

    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

public partial class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> StandardId { get; set; }

    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}
```

This looks almost the same, except:

1. In this example, the `Standard` class (equivalent to my `CustomerType`) has a navigation property back to a collection of `Teachers`, which my first example does not have. Is this just convenient to have if I want to get a list of all teachers for a given standard, or is it necessary to properly set up the relationship?
2. The properties in the second example are marked `virtual` and the first are not -- it seems that best practice is to make nav properties virtual, but is there a reason you wouldn't want to do that?

If it matters, I'm using MVC5 and EF6 and I just want to know if one example is right and one is wrong, or just two styles of getting to the same place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigational properties are to make queries easier for the programmer. Your examples are basically the same with the difference that in `Standard` you can access `Teachers` through query while in `CustomerType` you can not access `Customers` with this `CustomerType` because you do not have it as a navigational property. Nevertheless, you can always include `List<Customer> Customers` in `Customer Type`.

Also it is better to add virtual to your navigational property for the sake of lazy loading.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs, if you will never have to get the navigation property and just need a foreign key for sake of data integrity then you can simply add an integer and mark it as a foreign key. ex: instead of having a `CustomerType` instance, you can simply have a `CustomerTypeId` and that is it.

As for the `virtual` keyword, you can add it if you want to have a lazy loading enabled in your `DBContext`, cause EF generates proxy classes that inherits from your model classes and it overrides the virtual properties to add the needed logic to lazy load the navigation properties.

If you have a lazy loading disabled, then no need to mark any property as `virtual`